# Python Instance method syntax

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

**Edited the question because it was utterly unclearly stated***

So, I have a class Data, where many variables are being initialized as lists.
I would like to create a method with a syntax that would somewhat look like this:

```py
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        #I‘ve included only one element in the respective lists, but there are in fact hundreds of them. Just to give an Idea of the faceplate
        self.motors = [[‘MBuild_SCREWPUMP_01’],[‘341PDR-A01’],[‘Building’], [‘7.5kW’]]
        self.valves = [[‘TAG-Name’],[‘PandID Number’],[‘AREA’],[‘Power’]]
    def sort_by_PID(self):
        #here some code that would return a sorted list, it doesn’t work with embedded sorting methods since each list element is itself a list, whose order cannot change due to compatibility issues in other applications
```

and then later I would write something like this:

```py
data = Data()
some_list = data.motors.sort_by_PID()
some_other_list = data.valves.sort_by_PID()
```

and the two lists above would be sorted, according to their list[1]

so basically I guess i’m wondering if there is a way for a method to “look back” into the Class.instance_variable.structure (one or a few dots behind) and find there the instance variable it is supposed to alter.

or maybe the only way this is achievable is by instantiating with self.motors = Motors(), which would in turn have this embedded method.

Comment: As an alternative, could you do `def sort_by_name(self, name)` such that you could pass in "motors" and get back the sorted list of motors?  If that would work for you then your method could just do `return sorted(getattr(self, name))`

Comment: What are `B`, `C`, `A`, `W`, `Z`, `X`, and `T`? If they are just strings, then `sorted(data.motors)` gives you what you want. If not, `sorted(data.motors, key=some_func)` where `some_func` is a function that takes an object of whatever type those lists contain, and returns the key to sort it by, will do the job

Comment: you might want to try dataclasses:  https://youtu.be/vXgg0dFn7II

Answer (score 2):

In this instance you can do

```
sorted(Data.motors)
```

since the sorted() method is already implemented for you by python and does exactly what you're looking for.

Here's what the code would look like using sorted() provided by python.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.motors = [B, C, A, W, Z, X, T]
        self.valves = [B, C, A, W, Z, X, T]
        self.process_signals = [B, C, A, W, Z, X, T]
        self.general_signals = [B, C, A, W, Z, X, T]
        self.external_modules = [B, C, A, W, Z, X, T]
        self.automatics = [B, C, A, W, Z, X, T]

data = Data() # make sure not to name your variable the same thing as your class name
some_list = sorted(data.motors)
some_other_list = sorted(data.valves)
```

This wont change the original attribute though, to do that you'd have to do .sort() on the attribute, like this.
`data.motors.sort()`
Which is already implemented on the list class for you [by python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp).

In order to do **exactly** what you're asking for, you'd have to create another class and embed it in your Data Class.

So you'd have a Data class, and in that you'd have

```
self.motors = Motor()
```

and then in the Motor class you'd have method that does sort_by_name. However like i said above, since your motors and valves attributes right now are just lists, you can use the built in methods [provided by python.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp)